# What are the best practises using Docusign's 0Auth API?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, digital-signature

I'm using authentication code mechanism through Docusign's API for integration and works as expected.

Have a question regarding the documentation about implementation best practises, described in this [page](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-best-practice/)

Questions are related to the diagram at the end:

**Question1**

In ***Get the user's account ID, base URL and name*** (1st square) how do you recommend fetching the user/account information as before consent we don't know who is giving consent?

If it is related to users that may have given consent before, **is it even necessary**? If tokens already exist for the user, what is the purpose of verifying this scenario?

In the documentation it seems this is reinforced further with what is stated next:

[image]

How will we know what is the account/user information before the user gives consent?

**Question2** (Similar to above)

In ***Collect the account ID (GUID) and name of the user***, when no access token is found, I'm assuming we should redirect the user **immediately** so that the use gives consent again. Similar to the question above, in the diagram it indicates we should do this action "Collect account/user info" somehow before redirect for consent? We only know it afterwards as well, so is it needed?

It would be great if it would be possible to clarify the above!

[image]

Comment: Which OAuth flow are you using? Authorization Code or JWT grant?

Answer (score 1):

As Inbar commented, that diagram needs some work. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Here's my recommendations for user present (Authorization Code and Implicit grant flows) and user absent (JWT grant flow).

### All authorization flows

Determine if your users will typically use your application with a particular eSignature account or with any of their accounts. (It is common for customers to have access to more than one DocuSign eSignature account.)

If a particular account will be used, then provide an installation screen for your app where the admin can enter the account ID (use the guid format).

Your installation screen should also enable the installer to set
the DocuSign OAuth service provider, either **production** account.docusign.com or **demo** account-d.docusign.com

### User present: Authorization Code and Implicit grant flows

Your app may or may not have its own login sequence for users. Your app needs a DocuSign access token for making API calls to DocuSign APIs.

#### When your user wants to authenticate with DocuSign:

- Start the Authorization Code or Implicit grant flow.
- When the flow is done, your app has an access token.
- If the Authorization Code grant flow was used then you also have a refresh token.
- Use the oauth/userinfo API call to obtain information about the user:

  - Their name and email
  - The eSignature accounts they have access too, and which of those accounts is the user's default account
  - For each account, the name of the account and the `baseUrl` for making API calls to the account.
- If your app's users use a preferred account, then check that the user has access to the preferred account. Else, note the account id of the user's default account. (Also be prepared to handle the cases where there is either no userinfo response, no account or no default account for the user. These are infrequent DocuSign errors and can be fixed by contacting DocuSign Customer Support and referencing this [article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Empty-UserInfo).
- Use the `expires_in` OAuth response attribute to calculate your expires datetime. Then subtract 10 minutes so you have a buffer between the time you'll last use the access token and when it actually expires. You now have the `last_use` time.
- Store the user's information, including the account id, base url for the account, access token, and last_use datetime.
- If you have a refresh token, store it (and the user's information) in non-volatile storage.

#### When your application wants to make an API call

- If you have a current access token for the user (last_use datetime is after the current datetime) then use it.
- If the last_use time has passed, then use the refresh token if you have it. When refreshing the toke, you'll receive a new refresh token. Store it in non-volatile storage, overwriting the prior refresh token.
- If no refresh token, then your app will need to ask the user to authenticate again.
- Do not use oauth/userinfo again after either the token was refreshed or the user authenticated again. Keep and use the userinfo obtained after the person first logged in.

#### When your user wants to use a different account

Provide a "Switch accounts" feature to enable users to choose which of their accounts should be used. (Only applies if any account can be used with the application.)

### User not-present: JWT grant

- Your app's configuration screen will also need the user id in guid form. You can either store these values or look them up from DocuSign.
- Decide whether a specific account is needed or not (see above).
- Decide how the user will grant consent. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBziZ2TfFVs&t=2s) for more info.

#### First time your app needs an access token after a reboot

- Use the JWT user grant to obtain an access token
- As above, calculate the `last_use` datetime including a 10 minute buffer.
- Use oauth/userinfo as above to determine if the user has access
  the account or what the user's default account is. Also obtain the account's base_url.
- Store the information.
- Use the access token to make the API call.

#### Subsequent API calls

- Check the last_use datetime. If it hasn't yet occurred then use the stored access token. If it has occured, then redo the JWT user grant flow but do not make another oauth/userinfo call--use the prior information.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1** - You do not need to remember which user gave consent. That is not something you should do anyway, because users can revoke consent and then your information will be inaccurate. The system will ask for consent if needed (and if you ask for additional scopes it may be needed even if consent was given for example).

**Question 2** - You should redirect immediately, whether consent is needed or not is unclear, but the user will either have to login, or just redirected if they have a cookie and consent is also based on their circumstances.

I'll consent (no pun intended) that we can improve this diagram and make it easier to understand. I would suggest implementing a simple scenario first and seeing how it work before moving on to the more advanced scenario (by simple I mean every time a user need to log in as if it was their first time).